# Problem transcribing local audio file with google speech to text on node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, speech-to-text, web-mediarecorder

I'm trying to practice google Speech to Text with node js.
What I'm trying to do is use MediaRecorder to make an audio recording. I upload the audio to the server with multer and then transcribe the audio getting the text.

The problem is that the variable that should contain the transcribed text actually contains nothing at all. I've been trying to figure out the source of the problem for hours but no results.

Here is the html and javascript code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="audio" controls></audio>
    <button name="record">record</button>
    <button name="stop">stop</button>

    <a id="myLink">Telecharger</a>

    <div id="transcription">Transcription: </div>

    <script>
        var btnStart = document.querySelector('button[name="record"]');
        var btnStop = document.querySelector('button[name="stop"]');
        var audio = document.querySelector('#audio');

        var myLink = document.getElementById('myLink');

        btnStart.addEventListener('click', async () => {
            let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true, video: false});
            let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            mediaRecorder.start();
            let chunks = [];
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
                 chunks.push(e.data);
            }
            //function to catch error
            mediaRecorder.onerror = (e) => {
                 alert(e.error);
            }

            mediaRecorder.onstop = async (e) => {
                 let blod = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });

                 const formData = new FormData();
                 formData.append('audio', blod);

                 // Envoi du fichier audio au serveur Node.js
                const response = await fetch('/transcribe', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData,
                });

                let transcription = await response.text();
                transcriptionDiv.innerHTML = `Transcription: ${transcription}`;
            }
            btnStop.addEventListener('click',()=>{
                 mediaRecorder.stop();
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I use multrer to upload:

```js
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({

  destination: (req, file, callback) => {

    callback(null, 'uploads');

  },

  filename: (req, file, callback) => {

    const name = 'test-speech.wav';

    callback(null, name);

  }

});

module.exports = multer({storage: storage}).single('audio');
```

And the node js code:

```js
app.post('/transcribe', upload, async (req, res) => {

    try {
            const config = {
                encoding: 'LINEAR16',
                sampleRateHertz: 44100,
                languageCode: 'fr-FR', 
            };

            const audio = {
                content: fs.readFileSync('uploads/test-speech.wav').toString('base64'),
            };

            const request = {
                audio: audio,
                config: config,
            };

            const [response] = await client.recognize(request);
            const transcription = response.results.map(result => result.alternatives[0].transcript).join('\n');

            console.log('Transcription : ', transcription);

            res.send(transcription);

        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error while transcribing :', err);

            res.status(500).send('Error while transcribing');
        }

});
```

As I said above, the variable `transcription` does not contain any value. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the config you have provided, for sure. Try changing the encoding and stick to the doc in the sampleRateHertz. https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/encoding

I think that the correct encoding should be WEBM_OPUS, but try until you get the transcription right.

Comment: can you elaborate further on why you think the encoding should be `WEBM_OPUS` instead? what's different from the one OP used?